# contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods in magento 2

Tags: php, magento, abstract-class, magento2

run a setup:upgrade,setup:di:compile then shown this error

Fatal error: Class Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb::getResource) in C:\xampp\htdocs\mage-test\vendor\magento\framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory.php on line 45

Comment: Which versions of PHP and Magento 2 are you running?

Comment: @benJ  I'm using these version
php version 7.3.19 and
m2 version : 2.3.5p